# Windows Service starts then stops automatically

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a solution that has three projects. One is a service, one is a form, and one is a class library.

I use the form for debugging, my logic is complete now I would like to just call.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim Logic As New ProcessMail
    workTimer = New Timer(New TimerCallback(AddressOf Logic.ProcessMessages), Nothing, (1000 * 60 * 10), (1000 * 60 * 10))
    MyBase.OnStart(args) 
End Sub
```

So it fires off my code every 10 minutes. Why wont this work?

The service installs, I see it but it starts and stops, can anyone help me out with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: wow is it that bad of question to be downvoted ? If your gonna edit it for grammar at least finish the job.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me.  I wish people that downvote would leave a reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the event log.  Frequently, a windows service will stop because an exception is thrown.

Comment: do you mean the service events event log in event viewer or somewhere else

Comment: @kcbeard: The Event Viewer you find in Control Panel / Administrative Tools.  Under Windows Logs, exceptions should be in the Application node.

Comment: this would create a new question and that was a clear cut answer. Thanks Eric.

Comment: yeah thanks my .dll was just referenced the wrong way, thank you